# Como aceder ao upload do react native na API do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, react-native, upload

Tenho uma app em react native, tenho uma opção que o user pode alterar o seu avatar, estou a usar a biblioteca `ImagePicker` e tenho a API em Laravel.

Estou com problema em aceder a imagem escolhida no laravel eu estou dar um `request->file('avatar')` mas retorna `null`
não sei porquê, o que estou a fazer mal ?

**React Native**

```
handleChoosePhoto = () => {
    const options = {
      title: "Escolher Foto",
      takePhotoButtonTitle: "Tirar Foto...",
      chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: "Escolher da Galeria...",
      mediaType: "photo",
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: "images"
      }
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log(response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log("User cancelled image picker");
      } else if (response.error) {
        showMessage({
          message: "Foto de Perfil",
          description: response.error,
          type: "danger",
          floating: true,
          duration: 2850
        });
      } else {
        this.handleUploadPhoto(response);
      }
    });
  };

  handleUploadPhoto = async responseSource => {
    try {
      const id = this.props.user.id;
      const data = new FormData();

      const uriPart = responseSource.uri.split(".");
      const fileExtension = uriPart[uriPart.length - 1];

      data.append("avatar ", {
        uri: responseSource.uri,
        name: `avatar.${fileExtension}`,
        type: `image/${fileExtension}`
      });

      const response = await api.post(`user/dados/${id}/avatar`, {
        data
      });

      console.log(response.data);

      showMessage({
        message: "Perfil",
        description: "Dados actualizados com sucesso!",
        type: "success",
        floating: true,
        duration: 2850
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

**Laravel API**

```
$user = $request->user_id;

avatar = request->file('avatar');

return response()->json(['avatar' => $avatar]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver, perante varia pesquisa e varios teste, acabei por descobrir que na API estava sim a chegar. foram dois problemas.

**1**

Estava enviar o data fo formaData no body da requisição ou seja estava enviar como json e não como **Content-Type: multipart/form-data**

**2**

Na API estava a esperar de receber o file com o nome avatar que passei no formData mas depois de alguns testes descobri que ele estava a chegar la como avatar_ mudei e todo funcionou.

Vou deixar o código para ajudar alguém no futuro.

```
try {
  const id = this.props.user.id;
  const data = new FormData();
  let filename = this.state.imageSource.split("/").pop();

  data.append("avatar ", {
    uri: this.state.imageSource,
    name: filename,
    type: "image/jpeg"
  });

  await api.post(URL, data);

} catch (error) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa variável **api** é uma instância do axios?

Tente adicionar um header **Content-Type: multipart/form-data** à sua requisição.
Caso esteja usando o axios seria assim:

```js
const response = await api.post(`user/dados/${id}/avatar`, {
  data
}, {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
});
```

Comment: sim api e uma instância do axios, eu tentei adicionar isso e nada eu coloquei na api do laravel um $request->file('avatar') para verificar pelo console se pegava mas nada retorna null